# How do i set maximum number in a table on sql database server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

Please I have a SQL database project am working on and am asked to ensure that on my table `HumanResources.Booking`.

1. `Max_Num` should store maximum number of members allowed to use a facility at a given time
2. Actual number should store the number of bookings already made by the members for a facility. Its value cannot exceed the value of `Max_Num`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @ marc_s but please can u help me solve the question, am new to sql and i really need help on that project.

Comment: Am using SQL 2012

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server 2012?

Comment: This can be done on `SQL Server` through the use of an `Instead of Update` `Trigger` and a control value to set the `Max_Num`. However, this is generally not advisable to do on the back end database. Does your project involve some kind of web form or other application to enter booking data into? Generally it would be easier to implement what you are suggesting on the software that users are using to enter data.

Comment: Yes SQL Server 2012 @ The impaler

Comment: Thank you @ Edward. Yea it does not involve any web form or application...And i would appreciate if u can post the syntax here for me to see. thanks boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be difficult to do this with `constraints` on the actual table without using a `trigger` or `instead of trigger` (as Edward kindly commented) which just sounds like a bunch of problems down the road.  Yuck.

I would suggest the following:

- restrict permissions on the table so people can't insert/update the table
- use a `stored procedure` to do your inserts/updates
- put the business logic outlined in your question into the `stored procedure`

That way your data *should* be safe from the kind of updates you don't want, yet the application developers can still just throw their data at database: your `stored procedure`.  You can also then handle errors (people trying to break your business logic) nicely.

Note if you are planning on handling large amounts of data it will be well worth putting effort into optimizing your `stored procedure`.